# Karate UI is unable to simulate mouse hovering to obtain the tooltip value

Tags: karate

I attempted to utilize `driver.mouse().move(element.getLocator()).go();` in order to simulate mouse hovering and obtain the tooltip value. Unfortunately, this approach was unsuccessful as the tooltip div tag failed to populate. The error message I encountered was `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: cannot find locator`.

I am currently using karate version `1.4.0`.

Comment: `element.getLocator()` looks wrong to me. please search other answers, also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69948002/143475 (UI automation is hard). if you provide a live page, others here may help you

Comment: Yes, have tried by providing the locator like this `mouse().move("element").go();`. But, unfortunately this is also not working. Trying Angular tooltip similar to this one https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#tooltip-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this for the live example you provided and it worked:

```
* driver 'https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview'
* mouse().move('tooltip-overview-example .mat-mdc-button-touch-target').go()
```

Please do go through the documentation in detail, it can help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#mouse

Personally I feel a test trying to get the tooltip is a waste of time. Visual testing may need to be considered.

I was able to get the tooltip value like this:

```
* def tip = attribute('tooltip-overview-example button', 'mattooltip')
* match tip == 'Info about the action'
```